# Ajustar altura de una imagen a un div

Tags: html, css, imagen

Estoy haciendo una web para un proyecto en mi universidad. resulta que en mi web tenia una imagen de fondo con tamaño 1920x1080 que ocupaba todo el fondo de pantalla pero al reducir la altura del banner principal a 75vh (antes estaba en 100vh) este me recorta la imagen por debajo y no hay manera de que logre encuadrar bien la imagen, ni siquiera reduciendo el tamaño de la imagen manualmente.

Mi html:

```
  <section id="banner">
            <article>
            <img id="bannerimagen01" src="fondo.jpg" alt="" />  
            </article>
  </section>
```

Mi css:

```
#banner {
    min-height: 75vh;
    height: 75vh;
    position: relative;
}

#banner > article {
        -moz-transition: opacity 1.5s ease, visibility 1.5s;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s ease, visibility 1.5s;
        -ms-transition: opacity 1.5s ease, visibility 1.5s;
        transition: opacity 1.5s ease, visibility 1.5s;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 0;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Y poniendo `height:auto` y `width:auto` de `#banner > article` tampoco te funciona?

Comment: poniendo height:auto y width:auto en #banner > article la imagen me ocupa toda la pantalla y lo que quiero es que se ajuste a la altura de 75vh que he puesto en #banner

Comment: Utiliza la propiedad scale de CSS Con esto podrás escalar la imagen de la imagen , te paso el url de la documentación https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale.

Comment: La quieres tener de fondo?

Comment: si, son 3 imagenes de fondo que van cambiando cada 4 segundos, es decir tengo un script que me muestra un <article> distinto cada 4 segundos, con eso no tengo problema, pero si con ajustar la imagen a la altura del #banner

Answer (score -1):

Agrega altura máxima a **IMG** la cuál su **100%** será definido por el **75vh** de **#banner**.

```
#banner article img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Eso es incorrecto, si le dices a una imagen `max-height:100% `le estas diciendo que su alto maximo sea su alto natural, si la imagen mide 100px de alto y la pones en un div con 200px de alto, no crecerá mas alla de 100px.

Comment: Hice una prueba antes de publicar la respuesta y la imagen no sobrepasa al padre.

Comment: El ejemplo que mencionas de 100px que no crecerá en un div con 200px es correcto, sin embargo yo no dije lo contrario, el problema presentado es que esta utilizando imágenes 1920x1080 y necesita adaptarlas a la altura del artículo, y la respuesta que ofrecí resuelve dicho problema.

Comment: Ok, me sigue pareciendo un poco confusa tu respuesta (creo que se deberia decir `height:100%`, y no `max-height:100%` en este caso) pero te quito el voto negativo :) (no se si me dejara)

Comment: Bien por reconsiderar tú voto ;) Realiza otras pruebas con el ejemplo que mencionan y tal vez te parezca un poco menos confusa, cómo te dije antes, después de **hacer pruebas**, consideré el **max-height** sobre el **height** porque el primero **resuelve el problema** de recorte de imagen que presentan en la pregunta, algo que no obtuve con la segunda opción.

Comment: he intentado con #banner article img {max-height: 100%;} y tambien con height: 100% y sigo teniendo el problema de que me recorta la imagen, encontre una especie de "solucion" que es poner lo siguiente: #banner > article {background-size: 100% 75vh; } pero esto me distorsiona la imagen asi que sigo buscando otra solucion